# windows batch: "if exist" -- path exists but it says no -- why?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have this script in my batch file --

```
if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%" (
    echo JAVA_HOME '%JAVA_HOME%' path doesn't exist) --- (1)
else (
    echo Setting JAVA property to '%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java' --- (2)
        set "JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java")
```

`%JAVA_HOME%` was set to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45`. This location exists on my machine but the above code executes line (1), why ?

**FOLLOW-UP:**

It's driving me crazy, I have this script now --

```
if "x%JAVA_HOME%" == "x" (
  set  JAVA=java
  echo JAVA_HOME is not set. Unexpected results may occur.
  echo Set JAVA_HOME to the directory of your local JDK to avoid this message.
) else (
  if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%" (
    echo Here ----------------------------------> note this line !!
    echo JAVA_HOME '%JAVA_HOME%' path doesn't exist
    goto END
  ) else (
    echo Setting JAVA property to '%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java'
    set "JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"
  )
)
:END
```

the `%JAVA_HOME%` is set properly (it's `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45`). but when I run, I get this error --

```
prompt> test.bat
prompt> \Java\jdk1.7.0_45' was unexpected at this time
prompt>      echo JAVA_HOME 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45' path does not exist
```

what is going on? Please also notice that the line `echo Here` does not execute as well.

Comment: you have `not` in the keyword. So it will say no if it does exist

Comment: Enclose the paths in the echo statements in double quotes too, not single quotes, as the brackets are causing the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Raymond Chen once said](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/29/9914426.aspx) :

> The batch language was not designed; it evolved.

Which makes it full of quirks. One of them is that it is picky about parenthesis.

The following code works on my machine :

```
@echo off

if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%" (
    echo JAVA_HOME '%JAVA_HOME%' path doesn't exist
) else (
    echo Setting JAVA property to '%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java'
    set JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java
)
```

I used `) else (`, a single parenthesis on a line by itself, and removed the parethesis from the echo statement.

You might also want to check the double quotes. Puttint the variable name inside the quotes like you did will remove the quotes from value. Here is an example :

```
C:\>set "test=foo bar"

C:\>echo %test%
foo bar

C:\>echo "%test%"
"foo bar"
```

If you need quotes *in* the variable's value then put them on the right hand side, like this :

```
C:\>set test="foo bar"

C:\>echo %test%
"foo bar"
```

Starting from scratch, going for former gives you more flexibilty (see @foxidrive comment), but it all depends on what you have to work with.

Comment: +1  just commenting that the double quotes in the set command were ok, and are needed in many situations.

Comment: I agree. I was talking about the whole set expression. I added sample code to clarify my point.

Comment: Yes, I see that.  It's very useful to enclose the variable name too with quotes, so it is still protecting the long path name elements but you can then manipulate the variable without the quotes being a nuisance.

Comment: hi @ixe013, I have added some follow-ups to my previous problem, help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Your echo was sent to a file named `note`, because you used `>`.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a chat or a forum. If I answered your question, accept it. If you have other questions, post a new one. That way you will have the whole community to help, not just me. It will also have a better chance of helping fellow programmers with a similar problem.

Answer (score 3):

The parentheses in your JAVA_HOME path are messing up the `if` statements.  I know it is painful but I recommend using the 8dot3 name.

```
call :SET8DOT3 JAVA_HOME %JAVA_HOME%


:SET8DOT3
set %1=%~fs2
goto :END
```

So the whole thing becomes...

```
call :SET8DOT3 JAVA_HOME "%JAVA_HOME%"

if "x%JAVA_HOME%" == "x" (
  set  JAVA=java
  echo JAVA_HOME is not set. Unexpected results may occur.
  echo Set JAVA_HOME to the directory of your local JDK to avoid this message.
) else (
  if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%" (
    echo Here ---------------------------------- note this line !!
    echo JAVA_HOME "%JAVA_HOME%" path doesn't exist
    goto END
  ) else (
    echo Setting JAVA property to "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"
    set "JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"
  )
)
goto :END

:SET8DOT3
set %1=%~fs2

:END
```

Comment: If anyone knows of a way to have `if` statements contain parentheses in the conditional section, please let me know.

Comment: Maybe you should post a question on SO ?

Comment: Your code has the same bug as the OP's update. It creates a file named `note`

Comment: Fixed the echo redirection problem.

Answer (score 1):

Batch recognises "double quotes" to delimit a quoted string, **'but NOT single quotes'**

Hence, it's chapter 2 of parenthesis-confusion.

BTW -

```
if defined var (echo var is defined
) else (
  echo var is not defined
)
```

Is better than `if [not] "x%var%"=="x"`

And I'm perpetually bemused by the construct

```
if not something (echo not something
 ) else (
 echo something
)
```

What's wrong with

```
if something (echo something
 ) else (
 echo not something
)
```

which disposes of the logical gymnastics?

- but I suppose it's a matter of style - or possibly lack thereof...